# matplotlib autoscale axes based on the data appears on the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a plot with doulbe y axis, the code is very simple:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax_1 = ax.twinx()

ax.plot(x, y)
ax_1.plot(x_1, y_1)

plt.show()
```

However, my data contain significant fluctuations that make the left part nearly negligible, so I set x limit to truncate these "noises". The original and truncated plot are shown in below.

[image: Oringal & Truncated plot]

My expected plot is like the one below (it took me a minute to find optimum y_lims).
[image]
 I've found some similar questions how to autoscale y axes, their answers just don't work in my case:

`ax.autoscale(True, 'y')`|`ax.autoscale_view()`|`ax.relim()`

Because (maybe) the upper limit is decided by `y.max()` which belongs to "noises", are there any ways to autoscale y axes based on the data limit appears on the figure?